# Why will this code not print the answer lines when it compiles without an error? new to programming

Tags: java

I am just wondering why this code wont print the answer lines when no errors come up during compiling.  I am doing assignment #35 of learnjavathehardway(https://programmingbydoing.com/a/two-more-questions.html)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoMoreQuestions
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print( "Question 1: Does it belong inside or outside or both? ");
        String q1 = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println( "Question 2: Is it alive? ");
        String q2 = keyboard.next();

        if((q1.equals("inside"))&&(q2.equals("not alive")))
        {   
            System.out.println( "Then what else could you be thinking of besides a shower curtain?!?" );
        }
        if((q1.equals("inside"))&&(q2.equals("alive")))
        {   
            System.out.println( "Then what else could you be thinking of besides a houseplant?!?" );
        }
        if((q1.equals("outside"))&&(q2.equals("alive")))
        {   
            System.out.println( "Then what else could you be thinking of besides a bison?!?" );
        }
        if((q1.equals("outside"))&&(q2.equals("not alive")))
        {   
            System.out.println( "Then what else could you be thinking of besides a billboard?!?" );
        }
        if((q1.equals("both"))&&(q2.equals("alive")))
        {   
            System.out.println( "Then what else could you be thinking of besides a dog?!?" );
        }
        if((q1.equals("both"))&&(q2.equals("not alive")))
        {   
            System.out.println( "Then what else could you be thinking of besides a cellphone?!?" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation how to post Question here .. this is not a proper way of posting question on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your Code If use are using `Scanner.next()` method it won't take value after space . So if you give input `both` and `alive` without any space it will show you result but if you intent to take value after space use `Scanner.nextLine();`

See your code and comments beside it

```
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print( "Question 1: Does it belong inside or outside or both? ");
        String q1 = keyboard.next();//will not take any value after space


            System.out.println( "Question 2: Is it alive? ");
            String q2 = keyboard.next();//will not take any value after space
 //so if you enter "not alive" q2 will store only "not".
            //String q2 = keyboard.nextLine();
// this will take all character even after space
```